# Convert pixel x,y position on map to latitude and longitude

Tags: latitude-longitude, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, xy, web-mercator

My map takes up 100% width and height of the browser screen.. I have a draggable div that is super imposed over the map, I am am capturing this divs position using `offset();` to get the `pixel` top and left values. I would like to convert these values to latitude and longitude. Is this possible?

Comment: Only to the resolution of the pixel size, and only after deprojecting from Web Mercator.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a screen point to a map point using https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-MapView.html#toMap and then get the latitude/longitude from that point.

Comment: It's worth noting, since he was using a draggable div, that `toMap` also acceptes mouse events (like `dragend`)